# How can I tell which site collection template was used?

Tags: 2013, site-collection, template

I need to create another Site Collection that is the same as our current site collection. However, I didn't create the first one.

I know we are using a **Publishing Template**, but not sure it is a "Publishing Portal" or "Product Catalog".

Is there a way to tell? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of ways to find it.

1. simple one is Go to the view source of the SharePoint page >> Search for "SiteTemplateID" to find site template name SharePoint 2010.[image]
2. USe command Line tool     `stsadm.exe -o enumallwebs -databasename <content-db-name> > Template.txt` Now, Open the template.txt file and check for template
3. Use SharePoint Manager to find SharePoint site template. Navigate thru the site, and look for "Web Template"

[image]
Read more: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2010/09/how-to-find-the-site-template-used.html#ixzz430YEg4jx

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! This helped. I found the "SiteTemplateID" it's "BLANKINTERNET#0" and my sub-sites "CMSPUBLISHING#0". The definitions can be found here: https://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/06/sharepoint-2013-site-template-id-list-for-powershell.html